# Support for virtual IPMI in a VM?

Tags: virtualization, ipmi

This might be a silly question, but... Is there any hypervisor or other virtualization solution which supports a "virtual IPMI" for virtual machines? I.e. would allow access to something that looks like power control, a serial-over-LAN console, etc. to a virtual machine.

This is really not the right way for managing virtual machines, I know. I'm looking for this because we make heavy use of IPMI for systems management and it would be interesting/useful to integrate VMs into the same framework, and because it'd be useful to have such an interface when I use VMs as a dev environment for systems management tools.

Comment: It would definitely depend on the virtualization environment you're using.  A partitioning system like FreeBSD's "jails" or Solaris Zones/Containers or Linux vserver would not allow something like this to occur because they don't provide hardware virtualization, but a commercial product like VMWare might.  Ask your vendor, perhaps?

Comment: What's the meaning of `it'd be useful to have such an interface when I use VMs as a dev environment for systems management tools.`?

Answer (score 5):

I can't find reference to any hypervisor which implements IPMI, but there is some talk about implementing this in [libvirt](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=815136) and [qemu](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/qemu-devel/2012-05/msg00670.html).

Comment: Thanks, @mgorven. It's good to know someone else is thinking about this, even if it doesn't exist yet...

Answer (score 4):

These days, such a beast does exist for libvirt, called [VirtualBMC](https://github.com/openstack/virtualbmc).

Answer (score 2):

I have something like this in place in RHEV 3, where the VM's power management is easily done via a small script, and VNC/Spice and a serial console are available. Not IPMI as such, but the functionality is right there

EDIT: there is a fence-rhev agent available as well, so that would cover the power management part